# How to generate bag migration scripts in Fuerte?

Tags: rosbag, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do I follow this part of the [rosbag migration directions](http://ros.org/wiki/rosbag/migration) in Fuerte?

```
$ rosrun rosbag makerule.py MyMsg.saved myrule.bmr
```

The `makerule.py` and `savemsg.py` scripts are missing from the Fuerte `rosbag` package.

Is that a bug, or have they moved somewhere else?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30805/how-to-generate-bag-migration-scripts-in-fuerte?/) by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25443 on 2012-03-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since no one has answered, I created a [ROS defect ticket](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3908) in hopes of getting the problem resolved.

UPDATE: this was a bug, now fixed. Some scripts were not getting installed with the new catkin build system.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2